# How to get list of user having execute on all SPs?

Tags: sql-server

I have a user that's been given rights to execute all stores procs using:

`GRANT EXECUTE TO SQLUSERNAME`

I'm able to get list of all such SPs by using HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME on sys.producdes which gives me a list of SPs the user can execute.

1. I have tried exploring sys.objects/sys.database_permissions but this doesn't list the stored procs that the user can execute. So I'm thinking that the above command may have not granted execute permission at each SP level (granular) but at a higher level, maybe database level? What can I check for this?
2. I also want to get the list of users that have been granted such a permisison.

Comment: Kind of indirect, but maybe you could run `sp_helprotect` for each user (maybe dynamically) into a temp table

Comment: Something like `select su.name, *
from sys.database_permissions d
INNER JOIN sysusers su
 ON su.uid = d.grantee_principal_id
where permission_name = 'EXECUTE'
AND class_desc = 'DATABASE'`

Comment: @siggemannen - your query works only if permission is explicitly granted for the SPs. When granted execute without sp name, then it doesn't show up in this query

Comment: Worked for me when I tested locally

Comment: Oops I missed the `class_desc='DATABASE'` part. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With this query, you can tell which users have which permissions at which context.

Granting execute to a user without explicitly stating what object or schema you are granting on doesn't implicitly grant permissions to each object under each context. For example, granting execute on a schema to a user doesn't explicitly grant execute to each object under that schema. It only grants execute at the schema level context.

```
SELECT dp.class_desc as perm_context
     , dp2.name AS user_name
     , dp.permission_name
     , o.name AS object_name
     , o.type_desc
FROM sys.database_permissions AS dp
    INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS dp2
        ON dp.grantee_principal_id = dp2.principal_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.objects AS o
        ON dp.major_id = o.object_id
WHERE dp.major_id >= 0;
```

Instead what you will see is this -

```
perm_context         user_name     permission_name       object_name               type_desc
-------------------- ------------- --------------------- ------------------------- ------------------------
DATABASE             someuser      CONNECT               NULL                      NULL
DATABASE             someuser      EXECUTE               NULL                      NULL
DATABASE             someuser      INSERT                NULL                      NULL
DATABASE             someuser      SELECT                NULL                      NULL
DATABASE             someuser      SHOWPLAN              NULL                      NULL
DATABASE             someuser      UPDATE                NULL                      NULL
DATABASE             someuser      VIEW DEFINITION       NULL                      NULL
OBJECT_OR_COLUMN     someuser      EXECUTE               SomeProcedureName         SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE
SCHEMA               someuser      DELETE                sysrowsets                SYSTEM_TABLE
SCHEMA               someuser      EXECUTE               sysrowsets                SYSTEM_TABLE
SCHEMA               someuser      INSERT                sysrowsets                SYSTEM_TABLE
SCHEMA               someuser      SELECT                sysrowsets                SYSTEM_TABLE
SCHEMA               someuser      UPDATE                sysrowsets                SYSTEM_TABLE
. . .
```

If there is an `EXECUTE` grant on a number of stored procedures, then that user was given explicit `EXECUTE` permissions to that procedure -

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON Schema.StoredProcedure1 TO someuser
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON Schema.StoredProcedure2 TO someuser
GO
. . .
```

Note - I've excluded negative `major_id`s from the results since they denote `object_id`s for system objects.